# Avoid Permission Dialog when the app launches for the first time

Tags: android, permissions

I received a notice from google, saying "make sure the permission context message is shown before triggering any permission requests at launch"

But I just claimed the permission in my manifest.xml and a permission request will be shown automatically when it is launched, even though I didn't start to check/request for the dangerous permission.
On some other devices it won't appear.

According to the test video from google, I learnt that the dialog is shown on their device. I have added a context about the dangerous permission, but can't find a way to show it before the dialog at launch.

So my question is: what is the rule about whether it will show a permission dialog?
and how can I "make sure the permission context message is shown before triggering any permission requests at launch"

Answer (score 0):

> In MainActivity class declarations :

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS};
public int ALL_PERMISSIONS = 0;
public boolean CheckNoPermission = false;
```

---

> It is compulsory to ask permissions in runtime above Marshmallow devices this code should be in onCreate method

---

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
     ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
     ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
     ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
     ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
     ALL_PERMISSIONS  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
}
else
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ITS MARSHMALLOW OR LATER ANDROID VERSION DETECTED.......\n");
    Log.d(TAG, "REQUESTING USER PERMISSIONS..... waiting for user to grant....\n");

    for(int x = 0; x < PERMISSIONS.length; x++)
    {
         String ThisPermission = PERMISSIONS[x];

         if (checkSelfPermission(ThisPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
         {
               CheckNoPermission = true;
               break;
         }
    }
    if(CheckNoPermission)
    {

         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
    }
    else
    {
         // you already have permissions
    }
}
```

---

> Outside of onCreate method but inside MainActivity class another method to check if user has allowed or denied permissions :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length == 5)
    {
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
           // all permissions granted
        }
   }
   else
   {
       // one of the permission is not granted
   }
}
```

---

Enjoy .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can access device contact details above marshmallow device that time you need permission below that device no need permission.

this below method fetch device contact details if your device is marshmallow then need permission i add permission check like

First check permission like make custom method for that ..

```
    /**
 * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Then after make request for permission to user like below..

```
   /**
 * this method request to permission asked.
 */
private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ContactListActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ContactListActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

then after make get contact details method ..

```
  /**
 * Get the contacts of the user and add each contact in the mContactList
 * And finally pass the mContactList to the mChipsInput
 */
private void getContactList() {
    Cursor phones = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // loop over all contacts
    if (phones != null) {
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            // get contact info
            String phoneNumber = null;
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String avatarUriString = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
            Uri avatarUri = null;
            if (avatarUriString != null)
                avatarUri = Uri.parse(avatarUriString);

            // get phone number
            if (Integer.parseInt(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                while (pCur != null && pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }

                pCur.close();

            }

            ContactChip contactChip = new ContactChip(id, avatarUri, name, phoneNumber);
            // add contact to the list
            mContactList.add(contactChip);
        }
        phones.close();
    }

    // pass contact list to chips input
    mChipsInput.setFilterableList(mContactList);
}
```

when you need call getContact details method first check permission like below ..

```
        // get contact list
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions();
    }
    else {
        getContactList();
    }
```

and add contact permission into android manifest file like below ..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your app's targetSdkVersion is older than 26 and claimed the permission in manifest.xml. Then you install it on Android 8 or above device. When you launch it on first time, the system would always show the dialog ask if you grant the permission. If you choose to deny it. The system would say "This app was designed for an older version of Android. Denying permission may cause it to no longer function as intented.   CANCEL/ DENY ANYWAY"